# Need driver for Intel HD Graphics 4000; running Ubuntu 18.04; Dell Latitude E6530

Tags: drivers, dell

I have researched as best as possible before posting here.  Read several dozens posts and sites.  None fix my problem.

I just need to load the driver for the Intel HD Graphics 4000 card.  I have read posts on Intel, numerous Linux and Ubuntu sites, and Dell.  I find drivers for Windows but not for Ubuntu.

I've exhausted any ideas I could come up with.  Help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.  Here is the video card whose driver is loaded:

```
stu@dude-Latitude-E6530:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for stu: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:f6400000-f67fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: What is wrong with the i915 kernel module/driver you have?  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.1/gpu/i915.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!

Comment: I didn't know about i915.  For some reason it appears not to be on my system.  I found a posting and did:

Comment: I didn't know about i915.  For some reason it appears not to be on my system.  I found a posting and did:  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel;  then installed missing dependencies 'xorg-video-abi-23' and 'xserver-xorg-core'; then re-ran sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel.  No errors. but it's still not finding the Intel graphics card.  There's something I'm not doing, but don't know what that is.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look at your post, you'll see the detail `driver=i915` meaning your video is being handled by the *i915* kernel module (partially written & managed by intel). It is on your system, and is already in use (your post proves that). In computer terms it's correctly a kernel module, that commonly is referred to as a 'driver'.  Is there something wrong with the intel i915 driver you're already using?

Comment: FYI:  The HD 4000 details are just marketing detail to help *sell* the product.  The linux kernel ignores that, and deals only with the chipset on the board/card .. which your system has detected as intel i915 and is thus using the *kernel module* (driver) to operate it. There are rare circumstances where it can make the wrong decision (use the wrong kernel module (*driver*)) but you've not made that clear if it's an issue.

Comment: Intel is a company that adds needed code to linux (*a benefit of open source*), you just need to use a recent kernel..  however you didn't say which 18.04 kernel stack you're using (ie. the GA or original kernel, or a HWE [hardware enablement] stack kernel, a decision made when you select a ISO to download and install, though it can be changed post-install too)

Comment: guiverc, thank you so much for your GREAT, clear explanations.  That's just what I was hoping for.  I hope others will find this during their research.  I did uname and got: uname -a
Linux dude-Latitude-E6530 5.3.0-61-generic #55~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 22 16:40:20 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.  I do not know if I have HWE enabled.  The problem I was trying to fix, my monitor (ASUS VW246 LCD) seemed awfully dark when viewing videos, and controls wouldn't correct things, so I thought it was the driver, but maybe I'm wrong.  Any suggestions?  Also, should I update the kernal?

Comment: Details are easier to read if you edit your question and paste there, however you **are** using the hWE kernel. The GA kernel for 18.04 is 4.15, the HWE kernel was 4.18 (18.04.2 iso or 18.10 kernel), 5.0 (18.04.3 iso or 19.04 kernel), and 5.3 (18.04.4 iso or 19.10 kernel), and will become 5.4 when 18.04.5 is released (ie. 20.04 kernel). The HWE kernel always stops advancing when it reaches the next LTS kernel (*20.04 gets the bumps with HWE at that stage*)..  ps: you don't need to do anything to bump to 5.4 with HWE, it's automatic with normal upgrades post-install.

Comment: Thanks for all the help & education!